# How angularjs treat with class instance inside a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Currently I am creating instance of class in angular controller and using it. But I have a doubt its memory leak.

for ex.

```
MyApp.controller("myController",function($scope){
  var helper=new Helper();
  $scope.drag=new DragFun();
});
```

In the example,how angularjs will deal with class instances? Should I have to delete helper and drag manually or angularjs will pass it to GC?
I am little confused about memory leak as instance of Helper() and DragFun() will again gets created when this controller gets called.

Comment: `helper` is simple local variable, so work as standard local variable - deleted when function done, `$scope.drag` is field of _$scope_ object so it will be delete when _$scope_ is desctroyed

Comment: @Grundy even though helper is a local variable, it is declared in the call back function of controller. will it automatically gets deleted when scope destroyed?

Comment: If you have a doubt, you can use `$destroy` event to clean up all you need